# Sliding menu Issue

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am making menu like mobile menu in desktop. But when I click on toggle menu is slide with search box. How can I fix this problem?. I want when I click on toggle only menu will open search will be on same place.

> http://jsfiddle.net/5aru60qz/1/

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row menu_top">
    <ul class="mini-submenu">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="list-group">
        <span href="#" class="list-group-item">Firstname
            <span class="pull-right" id="slide-submenu">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </span>
        </span>

        <a href="product.html" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i><span>My Product & Service</span>
        </a>
        <a href="myprofile.html" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i><span>My Profile</span>
        </a>
        <a href="myorders.html" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-cubes"></i><span>My Work Order</span>
        </a>
        <a href="notification.html" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-bell"></i><span>My Notification</span>
        </a>
        <a href="rating.html" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i><span>My Rating</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: Just to get this straight ; 
You want it to slide *over* the searchbox instead of pushing the searchbox left?

Comment: Yes, Over the search box. I want all element in header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute positioning and set explicit depths for the search box and the menu using z-index.

Give the menu a background color, and make sure it covers the search box when folded out.

to give  you an idea :

```
div.list-group
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    z-index:300;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:20px;
    height:43px;
}
```

complete demo here :

http://jsfiddle.net/5aru60qz/6/

Answer (score 1):

You must to absolute positioning or the search field, or the menu (or both):

```
 input[type=search] {
     /*your stuff*/
     position : absolute;
 }
```

See it:http://jsfiddle.net/5aru60qz/4/

Answer (score 1):

when you use float:right; , you need to put your search and your menu in each of their own containers:

The menu:

```
<div style="height: 70px;">
    <div class="row menu_top">
```

..and the search:

```
<div style="height: 50px;">
    <form>
```

I added some height to them, so they wouldn't interfere with oneanother.

Fiddle here: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5aru60qz/5/)